# How to check if the date is today OR the future at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to stop users to enter invalid dates in an input and to make sure the date is either Today Or in the future. so no dates in the past should be allowed.

I have this code but this code only seems to look for the future dates. and it gives me invalid message even if the date is Today!

```js
       var selectedDate = '28-Jul-2019';
       var now = new Date();
       
       
       var dt1 = Date.parse(now),
       dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);
       
       if (dt2 <= dt1) { 
       
       alert('invalid');

       }else{
  
alert('valid');
     
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

**EDIT:**

Based on the comments below, I came up with this code and now everything I get is valid even if the date is in the past:

```
    var value = "29-Jul-2019";


var day = value.substring(0,2);
var month = value.substring(3,6);
var year = value.substring(7,11);

    var selectedDate = new Date(year, month, day);

    var now = new Date();

    var dt1 = Date.parse(now),
    dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);

    if (dt2 < dt1) {    

    alert('invalid');

    }else{

    alert('valid');

    }
```

Comment: You can just us the HTML5 date input element with it's `min` attribute set to the current date

Comment: @LucaKiebel, no i cannot. I need to do it using javascript.

Comment: How are users entering the dates then?

Comment: @LucaKiebel in a div with editabe content.

Comment: For starters you need  a valid date string or parse it to constructor arguments

Comment: @charlietfl, the code works as is. run it.. but its looking for dates in the futire only. ignoring the today.

Comment: That date string in firefox for example does not produce what you want it to and is going to be very inconsistent across environments

Comment: @charlietfl, I am using firefox as well.. what do yo mean?

Comment: Produces huge negative date value

Comment: Is string format consistent? If so parse it into it's individual year, month, day values and pass those to Date constructor

Comment: @charlietfl, the string format is consistent. yes.

Comment: Then split it up into it's parts and pass to new Date as separate arguments

Comment: @charlietfl, i have no idea what you mean!

Comment: `dt2 = new Date( yearFromString, monthIndexFromString, dayFromString)`

Comment: @charlietfl, please view my edit.

Comment: closer but you don't pass it to `Date.parse` and months are based on zero as start index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you want the selected date to be today or in the future, you should check for `dt2 < dt1` and not `dt2 <= dt1`. Otherwise it would only allow future dates.

Second, when you create a new date with `new Date()` you are getting a date object that also represents hours, minutes, seconds, etc. You seem to only be interested in year, month, and day.

So by parsing `28-Jul-2019` you are getting a date object with time `00:00:00` whereas you would get the current time when doing `new Date()`.

To work around this, you could set the time of the `now` object with `setHours`:

```
now.setHours(0, 0, 0);
```

With this, `selectedDate` and `now` will only compare year, month and day, which pass the condition if the selected date is today.

```js
var selectedDate = '07 28 2019';
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(0, 0, 0);

var dt1 = Date.parse(now);
var dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);

if (dt2 < dt1) {
  alert('invalid');
} else {
  alert('valid');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Update**

It seems to work better if you use the string with the format `MM DD YYYY` instead:

```
var selectedDate = '07 28 2019';
```

```js
var selectedDate = '07 28 2019';
var now = new Date();
now.setHours(0, 0, 0);

var dt1 = Date.parse(now);
var dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);

if (dt2 < dt1) {
  alert('invalid');
} else {
  alert('valid');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Huh? I'm getting "valid". Check again.

Comment: Simply can't rely on passing that string to Date.parse. Look at what it produces

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, that might very well be true. There are probably different browser implementations for this, hence the different result. The solution is obviously to just set the correct string in the first place (0 hours)

Comment: But that's irrelevant when the date comparing it to is 4000 years ago

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean?

Comment: I get a date in `-2019` when I run that parse in firefox console....4000 years ago

Comment: Don't forget that "new Date()" gives you UTC.
Depending on your location and the time of day, the date portion may or may not be on your localized current day.

Comment: @charlietfl indeed. Browser implementations of such strings seem to very a lot. More than I thought. I posted an update on a better supported format.

Comment: That updated format is not a valid ISO format either. The only proper way to handle it is parse the string into it's parts and pass those parts as individual arguments to Date constructor

Comment: @Chris, your updated code still gives me `invalid` error.

Comment: @charlietfl, I think we can both agree on that the best way to handle dates and all corner cases is to use a library. My answer only tries to solve OP's problem as a derivative solution from their code. In other words, an improved answer - not necessarily the best one. But sure, you're correct. I pointed out in my first comment that the full string should be used instead.

Comment: @JamesJuanjie, what browser are you using?

Comment: No library needed to split the string and pass each argument to Date constructor

Comment: @Chris firefox.

Comment: @charlietfl, true, but someone else commented on time zones. Generally, libraries are recommended. Dates are a pain

Comment: @JamesJuanjie, strange. Gives me valid. Maybe, it should print invalid for you? What time zone are you in?

Comment: @Chris, no it shouldn't. I'm in the UK and its still the 28th here .

Comment: Have been trying to help....is a simple string split to get the proper solution. If OP is asking only about local date then timezone shouldn't be relevant

Comment: @charlietfl that's fine. I realize that is a better solution, and you should consider posting it yourself. I was too focused on getting the string parsing to work since that is what OP tried to do. That being said, I don't take too kindly on sarcasm and that kind of attitude. It's getting old around here... /Thread for me

Comment: I think I'm gonna do this whole check on server side. its easier, more reliable and far less pain in the backside!